# Method That Checks For Value in Collection returns false Even When Said Value is Contained in Collection

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I am having an issue with my method below. I am expecting it to compare an inputted parameter against a collection of items. As my code is now it will only return true meaning it will only find the item in the collection if it is of type string, null, or int that is two characters or less. I would like my method to be able to find variables of any type. For example, in my test, I add 0.5 to the collection and pass a parameter of 0.5 to my method. Even though 0.5 is in the collection my method still returns false meaning it can't be found in the collection. I suspect the reason I am not able to find parameters of any type is because of something happing with their type when passing them to the parameter and the collection.

I have been messing around with this code for hours now and still can't figure out what the issue is. If you have any ideas or tips I would love to hear them. Thanks.

My Method:

```
public boolean contains(Object arg0) {      
//       For loop that searchs are current collection for arg0
        for (Object c : data) {
            if (arg0 == null) {
                System.out.println(arg0 + " value");
                return true;
            } else if (arg0.equals(c)) {
                System.out.println("found " + c + " and " + arg0);
                return true;
            } else {
                System.out.println("couldint find " + arg0);
                return false;
            }
        }

        return false;
```

Test for method:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Test
void testToSortedList() 
{
    ArrayCollection arrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
    ArrayCollection resultArray = new ArrayCollection();
    // add the objects to the collections

    arrayCollection.add("Test");
    
    resultArray.add(771);
    resultArray.add(.5);

    
    System.out.println(resultArray.addAll(arrayCollection));
    System.out.println(resultArray.contains(771));
    System.out.println(resultArray.contains(.5));
    System.out.println(resultArray.contains("Test"));
}
```

Comment: The root cause is definitely your use of `==` instead of `.equals`, but I feel like there might be a better duplicate.

Comment: BTW many collections - we have no information about what `data` is - have a `contains()` method .... BTW2 code may be working for (some)  literals since these can be interned or cached

Comment: Don't assume readers here know details about `ArrayCollection` you are using.  We can reasonably guess `data` is an instance variable of `ArrayCollection`, but we shouldn't have to guess.  The `ArrayCollection` or whatever your professor gave you might not be the same as another professor gave to other students.

Comment: What is the point of *returning* the result at the **very first** iteration step? Your code breaks out from the after dealing with first element.

Comment: `if (arg0 == null) { System.out.println(arg0 + " value");  return true;` should be outside and before the beginning of the loop. `System.out.println("couldint find " + arg0);  return false;` should be outside and _after_ the loop.

Comment: Why you're returning `true` when `arg0 == null` ? It implies that your collection always *contains* a `null` value, if not, consider changing or removing it. And why does this check reside inside the loop?

Comment: It isn't clear why the `if (arg0 == null)` is there in the first place. Is `data` not allowed to contain a `null` reference or is it allowed?  Why do you return `true` without looking in `data` if a `null` reference is passed to `contains`?